# Adobe Premiere Pro - Select timeline region and remove it

Tags: video, premiere

I'm new to Adobe Premiere Pro CC.
How do I select a region in the timeline using the keyboard and then delete it, like you'd do in Sony Vegas Pro?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily be setting In and Out points in the sequence timeline.

In and Out points can be set using the <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd> keys respectively.

[image]

Once you have made your select, press the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to remove the selection.

Make sure that the video and audio tracks you want deleted have 'track targeting' activated.

[image]

If you want to quickly remove the gap between all the clips, you can also right-click in the empty area and select 'Ripple Delete'.